# Project to Project reference specific Version in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing application that is plugable. The plugins are loaded via Assembly.LoadFrom(). In my solution I have 4 projects. A WPF, 2 DLL and another DLL that is a plugin for the app. The plugin project references one of the other DLLs.

When I build the Solution and run I was getting an error trying to use the plugin dll because it was expecting an older version of the referenced project. I had to clean and rebuild the plugin project to get it to run correctly.

So I assumed that specific version of the reference was set to true. But there is no specific version option in the properties window.

So now if I make changes to the referenced assembly and change version number I will have to clean and rebuild plugin as well even thought I did not change anything in that project. I can foresee that I will forget to do this step.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Where is this reference? Shouldn't need one if you are using Assembly.LoadFrom

Comment: WPF project is doing the Assembly.LoadFrom to bring in plugin. Plugin references another DLL (BLL) that is in the same Solution.

So: 
WPF -> BLL
Plugin -> BLL (This is where the issue is. Change BLL version Plugin still expects old version.)
WPF Loads Plugin via LoadFrom

Answer (score 1):

Would have expected

IPlugin - > Plugin

WPF -> IPlugin  -> (LoadFrom Plugin)

That way they only time you should have to rebuild everything is if IPlugin changed

However you work it the consumer of what is being loaded in LoadFrom, should never depend on the implementation.